# How to `map` an `Iterable` partially in Dart?

Tags: dart

Assuming I have a `List` as below:

```dart
final numbers = [1, 0, -1, 1, -3, 0];
```

I'd like to generate another list where `1` results in `true` and `0` results in `false` and skip the others. So, in other words, I'd like a method like `map` where I can also skip some elements. In terms of test, it would assert to:

```dart
expect(newList, equals([true, false, true, false]));
```

In this result, I'd like to skip `-1` and `-3` in the list.

How can I achieve this?

---

## Environment

- Dart 2.18.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ariel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005430/2926992) gave me a better idea. In the example of the question, what we'd like to filter out are two values, which are `1` and `0`. The real problem I'm dealing with right now is more complicated than this one, it has a wide range of lookup list. I haven't specifically asked "What is a more programmatic way to do this?" or "What if the lookup list has more values?".

So, if the values I'm looking for are more than these two values, a `List` of lookup values and [contains](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/contains.html) method would be better for my case.

```dart
final numbers = [1, 0, -1, 1, -3, 0];
final lookup = {1, 0};
final result = numbers.where((n) => lookup.contains(n)).map((n) => n == 1 ? true : false).toList();
print(result);
```

This has some drawbacks though, some of which that come to my mind are:

- **Performance is definitely worse than Ariel's answer**. My solution uses `contains`, which will perform look-ups in `lookup` rather than a simple byte-comparison with `n == 1`. So, it isn't great with large lists.
- **hashCode must be overriden for non-primitives**. It is easy to compare `int` with an `int` in this simple example, but if you have an instance, you need to override `hashCode`, otherwise Dart will compare the memory addresses rather than values.
- Using another collection type for `lookup` other than `Set` might also have performance impact because `Set` is inherently O(1) while the others might depend on their standard library implementation, but it's safe to assume they're going to be worse than `Set`. (See [Ariel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75005386/how-to-map-an-iterable-partially-in-dart/75005430#comment132361943_75005658)).

BTW, `lookup` does not have to be a `Set`. I've done it `Set` because `lookup` contains distinct values and the order is not important.

Comment: An important property of the `set` data structure (more correctly, its main purpose for existing) is the fact the membership testing is done in `O(1)` complexity no matter how large the set gets (due to the underlying hash-based implementation). This is exactly what `set` is designed for. So it will always be best to use `set` for the lookup in situations like these.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.where()` method to get a new iterable with only the elements satisfying a predicate, then use `.map()` to apply the transformation on the result.

```
final numbers = [1, 0, -1, 1, -3, 0];
final result = numbers.where((n) => n == 1 || n == 0).map((n) => n == 1);
print(result);

\\ (true, false, true, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most direct version would be:

```dart
var result = numbers.expand<bool>((n) => 
   n == 0 
       ? const <bool>[false] 
       : n == 1 
           ? const <bool>[true] 
           : const <bool>[]);
```

The `expand` method can do everything `map` and `where` can, plus more,

Not particularly efficient, but not all bad either.

Another approach is to use a `sync*` function:

```dart
var result = () sync* {
  for (var number in numbers) {
    if (number == 0) {
      yield false;
    } else if (number == 1) {
      yield true;
    }
}();
```

If you don't care about creating a list eagerly, that's a also the approach for a list literal:

```dart
var result = [for (var number in numbers) 
  if (number == 0) false else if (number == 1) true
];
```

Or:

```dart
const _map = {0: [false], 1: [true]};
var result = [for (var number in numbers} ...?_map[number]];
```

The options are endless. In practice, doing `where` and `map` is probably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`Iterable.map` is a 1:1 mapping; if your input has *n* elements, then the output must have *n* elements too.

Using `numbers.where(...).map(...)` works, but alternatively:

- Use `Iterable.map` first to map either to desired values or to an invalid sentinel value.  If your sentinel value is `null`, then you can use `Iterable.whereType` to filter out them out:

  ```dart
  var transformed = numbers.map((n) {
    switch (n) {
      case 0:
        return false;
      case 1:
        return true;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }).whereType<bool>();
  ```

  You might prefer this if you want all of your logic in a single callback.
- Use collection-`for` instead of `Iterable.map` and collection-`if` instead of `Iterable.where`:

  ```dart
  var transformed = [
    for (var n in numbers)
      if (isValidValue(n))
         transform(n),
  ];
  ```

  where you define `isValidValue` and `transform` functions with your filtering and transformation logic respectively.